# can't restart adb as root on android

Tags: android, adb

I know that by typing `adb root` I can restart my adb service on Android phone as root. But when I type it it just hangs forever saying that it's restarting the service:

```
$ adb root
restarting adbd as root
```

What could be wrong here? How to debug?

Then if quit it and run `adb shell` it also hangs. I then can `adb shell` into it only after I reboot my phone.

Comment: Actually, you cannot do this on consumer devices.  It may be that you have a customized device where someone attempted to make this work but did not get it right.

Comment: Thanks, for what device it's then? I have a Chinese JIAYU phone with superuser app provided. Could it be `someone attempted to make this work but did not get it right.`?

Comment: _Actually, you cannot do this on consumer devices_ - do I need to root my device to make it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong is your knowledge about adb - it can't be restarted as root by typing magic command.

Actually, `ro.secure` setting in `default.prop` file controls which user adbd will run :

- if `ro.secure=1` adbd will run under some user account. This is typical setting for production ROM builds.
- if `ro.secure=0` adbd will be run as root.

Comment: thanks, can you please answer [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770271/cant-restart-adb-as-root-on-android/27770600#comment43951619_27770271) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770271/cant-restart-adb-as-root-on-android/27770600#comment43951629_27770271)

Comment: How can I change the settings you specified? Where can I read more about ADB and its settings?

Comment: If I `root` it, will I then be able to run ADB as a root?